# After Effects Scripting - Set ease() for slider

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe, after-effects

I have an Audio Amplitude layer in After Effects and I want to programmatically add the following expression to the "Both Channels" slider:

```
ease(value, 40, 55, 0, 10)
```

Manually, the expression looks like this:
[image: Example of slider expression]

I tried to execute the following code, but unfortunately, *KeyFrameEase* only accepts two arguments.

```
var channelSlider = amplitude.Effects.property("Both Channels").property("Slider");
for(var i = 1; i < channelSlider.numKeys; i++){
   var easeIn = new KeyframeEase(40,33.33333);
   var easeOut = new KeyframeEase(40,33.33333);
   channelSlider.setTemporalEaseAtKey(i, [easeIn], [easeOut]); 
}
```

How can I add the *ease(t, tMin, tMax, value1, value2)* expression to the slider using After Effects scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
channelSlider.expression = "ease(value, 40, 55, 0, 10)";
```